# Is supplementation counter productive when your goal is getting a six pack/lean mass?

Tags: exercise, muscle, supplements, gym

I try hit the gym about 3-5 times a week (using a 3 day split program), and take something similar to [Supplements SA Ganic-F Insane](http://www.supplementworld.co.za/supplements-sa-ganic-f-insane.html)
 as pre-workout, and I've got protein shake that i use as a snack replacement/additive to me cereal in the morning.

I've never been a big guy, but in the same breathnever had things like decent muscle shape and a 6 pack. It has been my goal to achieve this since last year this time. My initial idea was I need to gain some mass, otherwise there wont be anything to tone/build off of?

Basically my question is, in my case...

Is supplementation counter productive when your goal is getting a six pack/lean mass?

Comment: You might find [my answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5670/what-is-the-most-effective-plan-to-get-abs)  to a similar question to be useful in understanding what goes into building abs.

Comment: i heard something that abs are made in the kitchen, but never knew if it carried any weight... thanks for the link, i shall def be trying that routine as well. seems legit :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the supplementation. The stuff you linked to probably isn't hurting your goal, probably not helping much either. Exercising and eating right, with plenty of rest and keeping stress low will help out in your goal more then the majority of supplements.

Meth addicts can be super skinny and have 6 pack abs. I was single digit body fat and working out and never had 6 pack abs. Some people get them, some don't.

Go by how you look, feel, and perform is the best way to do things IMO.

Answer (score 3):

For the goals you state, I recommend focusing on reducing your body fat.  Most reasonable healthy people have a nice six pack but it is hidden under body fat.  Adding mass will not do much to make those abs more visible.

By far the most effective tool for doing this is your diet.  I recommend a high protein, low carbohydrate diet - basically a variety of meats and vegetables, avoiding starchy vegetables like potatoes.  A good diet might be Tim Ferris's [Slow Carb Diet](http://www.fourhourworkweek.com/blog/2007/04/06/how-to-lose-20-lbs-of-fat-in-30-days-without-doing-any-exercise/).

Of course you should continue working out, but I think diet will be a much more effective tool for your goals.