# Will Musclecore x and Androsolve help bootstrap my fitness routine to lose weight?

Tags: supplements, nutrition-information

## Intro/Disclaimer:

- I'm quite ignorant about fitness. I don't have a sharp body with 6
  packs but I'm not horribly fat, just some belly (1.75m, 72 kg, male, 25yo).
- I'd like to have a sharper body and hopefully get the famous 6 packs.
- I started to go to the gym some months ago, once/twice per week without a real plan nor any diet change. Of course I didn't get any exterior visible result other than feeling a little bit "better" in general.
- I'm questioning two specific branded product because I'm not sure of what they contain, I'd make me happy if the answer mention similar product or what kind of ingredients I should look for, or avoid.

Now I've read the claim that ingesting some "stuff" like MuscleCore X and Androsolve daily should help dramatically and fast towards this goal. One pill a day of each product for some period.

See this [translated link](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://www.menhealthsix.com/promotion/&prev=/search?q=musclecore%2bandrosolve%2bmen%2527s%2bhealth&hl=en&biw=1301&bih=682) for instance. I'm not entirely sure what they contain and I'm wondering if they are worth to bootstrap a healthy lifestyle and helping me getting a nicer body for the summer.

And now...

## Questions

1. What do the two products really contain?
2. Is their claim true?
3. Are there counter notable side effect?

Comment: 1. Check the ingredient list. 2. Probably not. 3. This site isn't well suited for giving advice about pharmaceutical products.

Comment: Given your goal, have you considered switching to a proper strength training plan and diet? There are many questions on this site that answer questions about losing weight and building muscle.

Comment: @Kate is this considered pharmaceutical? I did think I should do some research to lose fat and build up muscle, I was just surprised they have such magical claims.

Comment: You may want to check out this question [about abs](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5670/what-is-the-most-effective-plan-to-get-abs/5671#5671). It explains that diet is the key to reducing body fat so that you can better see your abs and muscle definition.  As @Kate suggests to get to your goal you need a plan that includes exercise and diet.  Congrats on starting in the gym and feeling better!

Comment: It's very very thin on being related. You are pretty much asking straight pharma type questions.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things regarding supplement companies that you need to understand:

- They over promise and under deliver
- The majority of your results will be from a proper diet and exercise
- The less information you can get from the manufacturer's web site, the less you should trust them

It appears that Musclecore X uses certain BCAAs, namely [arganine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arginine) to "boost NO2" in the blood.  There's a few supplements that use the claim that increase in nitrous oxide (NO2) helps build muscle.  It is also important to note that arganine is readily available in a number of common foods.  There is a [semi-scientific study on Bodybuilding.com](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/south28.htm) using a different product with similar claims.  The pertinent information is quoted below (emphasis is mine):

> From the results of the test, it is obvious that the test group made considerable gains in lean body mass compared to the group that received the placebo. Each bodybuilder in the test group [with the exception being test subject number three] made gains from the supplement, and the gains were roughly equal for each bodybuilder.
>
> **Test subjects reported a difference in vasodilation, increased blood flow to skeletal muscles, increased oxygen transport resulting in quicker recovery following strenuous exercise**, and reported better pumps resulting from exercise. All three test group subjects indicated a pronounced increase in libido.
>
> **None of the test subjects demonstrated increases in strength or stamina**, and test subject two indicated an **increase in blood pressure**. Some of the subjects experienced **hot flashes, spontaneous sweating, diarrhea and fatigue**.
>
> Of the nine testable label claims outlined above, this nitric oxide supplement satisfied seven. Although not directly testable, the dosing procedure allows for the supplement to be digested over a ten hour period of time, thus satisfying the last label claim.
>
> **Therefore, the supplement, in this test, proved to be successful in two persons by satisfying 77% of its stated label claims.**

The three test subjects were a beginner, intermediate, and advanced bodybuilder.  The advanced bodybuilder did not receive much affect.

Androsolve is a non-steroidal "testosterone booster".  Products in this class fail to increase your testosterone much above normal.  If you have low testosterone levels (T levels), a blood test at your doctor can tell you that, then the product may work.  Although, if you typically eat a very low fat diet, simply increasing saturated fat intake can bring your T levels to normal.  Other than that, most studies I could find indicate that testosterone boosters as a class of supplement provide at best inconclusive results.  The only proven way to increase T levels above normal is to use steroids, which has its own risks.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what these products contain, what their claims are, or what side effects they have. Supplements that work exist: it seems to me that creatine, whey, vitamin D, and steroids are well proven to enhance the results of hard work. But that doesn't mean that someone new to working out should consider them, nor any other supplement.

## STOP RELYING ON CRUTCHES

Fitness is about hard, consistent work. Busying yourself with supplements distracts from hard, consistent work. Putting money into well-marketed powders and other voluptuously-priced products will lead you to think that they, instead of your sweat and diligence, are the *sine qua non* of success.

We all want quick, easy fitness. Supplements are primarily a way for advertising companies to make money from that desire. Supplement companies hide the fact that fitness takes time and effort.

Instead of putting your hopes for a six-pack into some slimy capitalist's wallet, try buckling down on your diet and exercise. Focus on what you know will make a difference: doing the hard work of lifting heavy weights and making yourself tired. Take the time you would spend researching MandroQuickAndEasyResults and put it into cooking your own meals and finding a rational workout program.